# Is there an implementation of the max-p-region model in R?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, geospatial

The question says it all. I am wondering whether there is an implementation of this specific regionalization algorithm in R. I found implementations of the SKATER and REDCAP algorithms but not the max-p region model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found one in using rgeoda - an R package GeoDa